# Is it possible to (permanently) change the default style and size of matplotlib plots (plotted inline in Jupyer notebook)?

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook

At the moment.  Each time I load up a Jupyter Notebook and am going to be using Matplotlib, I will set the default style and size for all the charts to be output inline.

For example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline
plt.rcParams['figure.figsize'] = [16,8]
plt.style.use('ggplot')
```

This results in a consistent size and style for the rest of the notebook session.

However, is there a way to make these changes permanent, so that each time I load up the Jupyter notebook, I will not need to type in these two lines of code:

```
plt.rcParams['figure.figsize'] = [16,8]
plt.style.use('ggplot')
```

but the chart will still default to those size and style settings?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

You can create custom style by locating your matplotlib config directory with

```
import matplotlib as mpl
mpl.get_configdir()
```

should be something like `~/.config/matplotlib`, creating `stylelib` directory (if not exists) and adding there your custom style file called `<name>.mplstyle`.

You can import your style with `mpl.style.use('<name>')` (without .mplstyle).

If you want to make permanent changes you have to locate the matplotlibrc file with `mpl.matplotlib_fname()` and edit the defaults for each property  you want to change.

Comment: And be sure to read the disclaimer/instructions at top of the `matplotlibrc` file.